# Javascript variable hoisting ("is already defined" jshint error)

Tags: javascript, jshint

Because of javascript variable hoisting, jshint complains about :

```
function test() {
    ...
    if( cond1 ) {
        var a = ...
        //do something with a
    }
    ...
    if( cond2 ) {
        var a = ...
        //do something with a
    }
    ...
}
```

because it's equivalent to :

```
function test() {
    var a;
    var a;
    ...
    if( cond1 ) {
        a = ...
        //do something with a
    }
    ...
    if( cond2 ) {
        a = ...
        //do something with a
    }
    ...
}
```

**Does the first approach can lead to bugs in some code ?**

Comment: I think this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162561/whats-wrong-with-defining-javascript-variables-within-if-blocks/1162756 is exactly the same to your, so I'd recommend you read it.

Comment: Yes an no, it may depends but i definitely wont recommend this. Javascript is permissive, so it'll accept you having 2 vars with the same name in the same scope, therefore whenever you'll try to do something with thoses vars, JS might not use the correct var.

Comment: large enough chunks of code, if you think some variable is scoped to a particular block, but it isn't, you could get some bugs.

Comment: Everything that can be somehow unexpected to someone can lead to bugs. Reusing variables of the same name for different purposes can be error-prone as well when you forget the second initialisation.

Comment: `JS might not use the correct var` - there will only ever be one

Comment: @AlexTodef Thank you, I do have read it, but it doesn't answer the question : can it lead to bug ?

Comment: @JaromandaX have an example in mind ? Because I don't find one, so I can't convince myself.

Comment: not really, I think as @Bergi said, it's more likely to be an issue if the second one is uninitialised - that is easy to show