# JAVASCRIPT Global Variable become undefined inside a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, settimeout

Someone can explain me why this variable become "undefined" ?

```js
var a=1;
var cond=false;
alert(a);

setTimeout(function(){ 

 alert(a); // <---------------- WHY IS UNDEFINED????
 alert(cond);
  if (cond==true) var a=2; // <------ IF I COMMENT THIS OR SET cond=false, WHY a IS UNDEFINED???
 alert(a);
}, 500);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use window.a an it's work.

Comment: Hi Quentin, can you tell me the link of duplicate question? thanks.

Comment: the link is in the banner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162561/whats-wrong-with-defining-javascript-variables-within-if-blocks

Comment: This is also a dupe of [Surprised that global variable has undefined value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9085839/4642212).

Comment: Ok Thanks Nelson.

Comment: Thanks also to Xufox.